# How to line break in java

Tags: java

I am using `"\n"` as a line break in Thread but it's not working. I went through a lot of SO answers which suggest using 
`System.getProperty("line.separator");`
but that also does not work for me..

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

final ReentrantLock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
final ReentrantLock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

Runnable try1_2 = getRunnable(lock1, "lock 1", lock2, "lock 2");
Runnable try2_1 = getRunnable(lock2, "lock 2", lock1, "lock 1");

new Thread(try1_2).start();
new Thread(try2_1).start();

}

private Runnable getRunnable(final ReentrantLock lock1, final String lock1Name, final ReentrantLock lock2, final String lock2Name) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                if (lock1.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {

                    System.out.println("1"+lock1Name + " acquired in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    text_3.setText(text_3.getText() +"1"+lock1Name + " acquired in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    if (lock2.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {

                        System.out.println("2"+lock2Name + " acquired in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        text_3.setText(text_3.getText() + "\n"+"2"+lock2Name + " acquired in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } else {

                        System.out.println("3"+"Could not acquire "+lock2Name + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        text_3.setText(text_3.getText() + "\n"+"3"+"Could not acquire "+lock2Name + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                        lock1.unlock();

                        System.out.println("4"+lock1Name + " released in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                        text_3.setText(text_3.getText() + "\n"+"4"+lock1Name + " released in thread " + Thread.currentThread());

                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("5"+"Could not acquire " + lock1Name + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                    text_3.setText(text_3.getText() + "\n"+"5"+"Could not acquire " + lock1Name + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } finally {

                if (lock1.isHeldByCurrentThread()) lock1.unlock();
                if (lock2.isHeldByCurrentThread()) lock2.unlock();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

output is as follows:

`1lock 2 acquired in thread thread-1 1lock 2 acquired in thread thread-0....`

I would like it to be as follows:

`1lock 2 acquired in thread thread-1 
1lock 2 acquired in thread thread-0....`

Comment: what's not working? give example of actual and expected output

Comment: Can you please isolate code causing troubles?

Comment: I replaced "brake" with "break". Please rollback if that wasn't your intent.

Comment: A wild guess --> are you showing text_3 in  html?

Comment: nop in jframe .
text_3 is jLabel

Comment: which OS? Windows/linux/OS X??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` like this,

```
 String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

 //then insert newLine variable as this :
 text_3.setText(text_3.getText() + newLine+ "2 " + lock2Name +
 "acquired in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting text as `"<html> this is <br> test</html>"`?

Comment: yes it not worked on the JLabel.i changed JLabel to TextArea..now its working.

Answer (score -1):

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        out.print("Hello and welcome!");

        String new_Line = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        System.out.println(new_Line);
        int i;

        for (i=10; i <=15; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).